# Web Audio API Constraints and AudioContext Graph

Tags: javascript, web, audio, webrtc, constraints

I am doing some audio processing with web audio api using JavaScript and I need an advice.

I am trying to do something like this.

```
const stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia 
{
    audio: true,
}

// Adding some constraints to the stream
for await(const track of stream.getAudioTracks()){
    await track.applyConstraints({echoCancellation:true, noiseSuppresion:false,....});
}


// Creating source and destination 
const source = context.createMediaStreamSource(stream);
const destination = context.createMediaStreamDestination();

// Filtering some audio
source.connect(filter);
filter.connect(destination);

// Applying new constraints after filtering
for await(const destTrack of destination.stream.getAudioTracks()){
    await destTrack.applyConstraints({autoGainControl:true...});
}
```

But after trying to apply new constarints to the `destination` I get error `OverconstrainedError {name: 'OverconstrainedError', message: 'Cannot satisfy constraints', constraint: ''}`. Why is `error.constraint === ''` ? How resolve this issue?

Comment: I'm seeing the same issue with a tab from `getDisplayMedia`. Applying constraints to the video track is fine, but any constraint applied to the audio track gives the same `OverconstrainedError` with an empty `constraint`. Both Chrome and Edge have this issue.